# Show the function is concave function but not strictly concave

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, convex-optimization

For an optimisation problem, it is required to prove: is the utility function $$f(\lambda X)=−\frac{1}{\alpha}\log\left(\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{()}\}\right),$$ *strictly concave* (strictly convex-up) function  of the $\lambda$ on an open set?

Here  $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$, $n$ is a sample size, $^{()}$'s are random samples from leaner space $X$. The notations are borrowed from [(Miyahara, 2010)](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/realopn/3/2/3_2_185/_pdf/-char/en), $g_X(\lambda):=f(\lambda X)$ is a scaled value measure and $\lambda$ is a scale parameter.

From first principles: A twice differentiable function of one variable is convex-up (strictly convex-up) on an interval if and only if its second derivative is non-negative (negative) there. In my case I should test: $f''_{\lambda \lambda}(\lambda X)<0$.

My solution is:

$$f'(\lambda X)=−\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{n}(\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(1)}\}+\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(2)}\}+\ldots + \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(n)}\})\right)\right)'=\\
=−\frac{n}{\alpha}\cdot \frac{\left(\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(1)}\}+\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(2)}\}+\ldots + \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(n)}\}\right)'}{\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(1)}\}+\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(2)}\}+\ldots + \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(n)}\}}=\\
=−\frac{n}{\alpha}\cdot \frac{{\sum_{i=1}^n (\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}})'}{\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}}=\\
=−\frac{n}{\alpha}\cdot \frac{-\alpha{\sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}}=\\
=n\cdot\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}}.$$

$$f''(\lambda X) = \left(n \cdot \frac{{\sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}}\right)'= \left(\frac{u(\lambda)}{v(\lambda)}\right)'=\\
=n \cdot\frac{({\sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}})'\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\} - \sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}\cdot(\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})'}{(\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})^2}=\\
=n \cdot \frac{{\sum_{i=1}^n (X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}})'\cdot \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\} - \sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}\cdot(\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})'}{(\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})^2}=\\
=n \cdot \frac{{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}((X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}})'  -  X^{(i)}\cdot(\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})')}{(\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})^2}=\\
=n \cdot \frac{{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}((X^{(i)}\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}})'  -  X^{(i)}\cdot(\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})')}{(\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})^2}=\\
=n \cdot \frac{{\sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)} \cdot \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\}\cdot  (\color{red}{(\exp\{−\alpha \lambda X^{(i)}\})'-(\exp\{−\alpha \lambda X^{(i)}\})'})}}{(\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})^2}=0.
$$
I have found that $f''_{\lambda \lambda}(\lambda X)=0$ because in the numerator we have
$((\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})'  -  (\exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{(i)}\})')=0$

and therefore $f(\lambda X)$ is not *strictly concave*, it is the *concave* function only.

**Question.** I need the solution verification or critical comments.

My be this [Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286520/is-the-logarithm-of-increasing-not-necessarily-strictly-function-is-concave) is usefull for verification.

**Literature**

[Miyahara Y. (2010). “Risk-Sensitive Value Measure Method for Projects Evaluation,” J. Option and Strategy, 2, 185-204.](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/realopn/3/2/3_2_185/_pdf/-char/en)

Comment: That is a peculiar and confusing way to define $f$.

Comment: Do you mean left or right side of $f$?

Comment: Normally one would define $f(x) = ...$

Comment: I have updated the question and provided the ref on the original paper where the function's notation were used.

Comment: are the $X^{(j)}$ nonnegative?

Comment: Is your expression a function of $\lambda$ or of $(X^{(1)},\ldots,X^{(n)})$? the statement is not very clear.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, $X^{(j)}$ can be negative. The expression is a function of $\lambda$.

Comment: @Nick Why not simply $f(\lambda)$?

Comment: @Nick Your 3rd paragraph, where did you see that? Indeed, for example, $f(x) = -x^4$ is strictly concave on $\mathbb{R}$, however, $f''(x) = -12x^2$ is not negative on $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, it can be zero).

Comment: @RiverLi, I have used notations from https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/realopn/3/2/3_2_185/_pdf/-char/en , look at page 193.

Comment: @RiverLi, in the paper https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/realopn/3/2/3_2_185/_pdf/-char/en one can see the classical definition of concave: $v(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y) \leq \lambda  v(X) + (1-\lambda) v(Y)$ for $0\leq X \leq 1$, page 189

Comment: @Nick No, I mean the strictly concavity. A strictly concave function  does not necessarily $f''(x) < 0$. For example, $f(x) = -x^4$ is strictly concave, however, $f''(x) = -12x^2$ is zero at $x = 0$.

Comment: If $n=1$ then $f$ is linear in $\lambda$, so not strictly concave.

Comment: @daw $n$ is a sample size, which is usually not equal to one.

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr As noted by River Li in the comments, the claim *A twice differentiable function of one variable is strictly convex on an interval if **and only if** its second derivative is positive there* (emphasis added) is not correct. The stated condition is sufficient, but not necessary: If $f$ is twice differentiable on some interval $[a, b]$, if $f''(t) \geq 0$ for all $t$ in $[a, b]$, and if the set $Z = \{t \in [a, b] : f'(t) = 0\}$ contains no open interval, such as a finite set of points (as in the question), then $f$ is *strictly* convex on $[a, b]$.

(This is analogous to the fact that a differentiable function with non-negative first derivative is *strictly* increasing if its derivative does not vanish identically on any open interval. An example such as $f(x) = x - \sin x$ has infinitely many critical points; an example where the critical points accumulate is left as an exercise.)

---

The usual proof is to fix points $x < y$ in $[a, b]$ arbitrarily, and consider the function
$$
g(t) = g_{x,y}(t) = f\bigl((1 - t)x + ty\bigr) - [(1 - t)f(x) + tf(y)],\quad 0 \leq t \leq 1,
$$
which measures the difference between height of the graph of $f$ and the height of the secant line through $(x, f(x))$ and $(y, f(y))$. The chain rule gives
$$
g''(t) = (y - x)^{2} f''\bigl((1 - t)x + ty\bigr).
$$
Particularly, $g$ is twice differentiable on $[0, 1]$, $g''$ is non-negative, and $g''$ does not vanish identically on any open interval.

**Lemma**: The maximum of $g$ on $[0, 1]$ is $0$, and the minimum is strictly negative.

*Proof*: Assume contrapositively that $g$ achieves a positive value at some point $t_{0}$. The mean value theorem applied to $g$ on $[0, t_{0}]$ implies there is a $z_{1}$ with $0 < z_{1} < t_{0}$ such that $g'(z_{1}) = g(t_{0})/t_{0} > 0$; and the mean value theorem applied to $g$ on $[t_{0}, 1]$ implies there is a $z_{2}$ with $t_{0} < z_{1} < 1$ such that $g'(z_{2}) = -g(t_{0})/(1 - t_{0}) < 0$.

The mean value theorem applied to the derivative $g'$ on $[z_{1}, z_{2}]$ now implies there is a point $z$ where $g'(z) = (g'(z_{2}) - g'(z_{1}))/(z_{2} - z_{1}) < 0$, contrary to hypothesis. This completes the proof that $g$ is non-positive on $[0, 1]$.

If the minimum of $g$ on $[0, 1]$ were $0$, then $g$ would be identically $0$, and consequently $f$ would be affine, contrary to the hypothesis that $f''$ does not vanish on any open interval. This completes the proof of the lemma.

**Corollary** If $[s, t] \subseteq [0, 1]$ and $g(s) = g(t) = 0$, then the minimum of $g$ on $[s, t]$ is strictly negative.

The proof of the lemma goes through with obvious changes of endpoint.

Our goal is to show $g(t) < 0$ (strict inequality) for $0 < t < 1$.

Suppose contrapositively that $g(t_{0}) = 0$ for some $t_{0}$ with $0 < t_{0} < 1$. By the corollary, there exist points $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ such that

- $0 < s_{1} < t_{0} < s_{2} < 1$;
- $g(s_{1}) < 0$ and $g(s_{2}) < 0$.

Connecting the corresponding five points on the graph of $g$ gives a "w"; a mean value theorem argument similar to those above shows $g''$ is negative at some point of $(s_{1}, s_{2})$, contrary to the hypothesis on $f$.

We have shown that $g$ is strictly negative on $(0, 1)$, i.e., that the graph of $f$ lies strictly below its secant line over $(x, y)$. Since $[x, y] \subseteq [a, b]$ was arbitrary, we have established strict convexity of $f$.

Comment: You have significantly refined the convexity definition. In my case, $-\infty <a <X^{(i)} <b <\infty$ and I have shown that $f'(\cdot) \neq 0$, but $f''(\cdot) = 0$. Is it possible to assert that the original function $f(\lambda X)=−\frac{1}{\alpha}\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\{−\alpha \lambda ^{()}\}\right)$ is not strictly convex.

Comment: I'd understood that (i) You know the function in question is strictly convex (or is asserted to be); (ii) you'd shown $f''$ is zero at finitely many points; (iii) you were asking how the second derivative being zero could be compatible with strict convexity. I didn't, however, check your calculation line by line, and it's possible I misunderstood either your notation or what you were asking. (That said, if $f'\equiv0$, then $f$ is affine, which is not the case for this $f$.) <> If this answer doesn't address your question I'm happy to delete it.